# How can i set when i use pip3 while using python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

when i boot, i use rc.local for auto start at jetson.
in rc.local,i worte like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/.bashrc
python3 /home/dinsight/Desktop/test.py
```

`test.py` is code for check python version, numpy version.
python3 version is `3.6.9`.
but numpy version is `1.13.1`.

when i use pip3 list , numpy version is `1.15.1`

when i use pip list , numpy version is `1.13.1`

so i want use python3, pip3 package.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an alias in the `~/.bashrc`
just add this line to `~/.bashrc` :

```
alias pip=pip3
```